# How to Set Bluetooth device Discovery Timeout to 1 hour(3600) seconds and Never Time out in android

Tags: java, android, android-intent, bluetooth, bluetooth-device-discovery

I am working on Bluetooth App where I want to add the functionality of Manually configuring the Discoverable Timeout Period.When i set DISOVERABLE_DURATION to 120 or 300 it works fine.However it does not provide any response in onActivityResult() when i set it to 3600 seconds.

Similarly I have set DISOVERABLE_DURATION to 0 for Never Time out which not working too.

I have Searched a lot and found that similar Bugs were reported but i could not be able to Find an appropriate Solution.

I am firing the following Intent

```
Intent discoverableIntent = new Intent(BluetoothAdapter.ACTION_REQUEST_DISCOVERABLE);
discoverableIntent.putExtra(BluetoothAdapter.EXTRA_DISCOVERABLE_DURATION,DISOVERABLE_DURATION);
startActivityForResult(discoverableIntent,REQUEST_DISCOVERABLE_BT);
```

Please provide me an appropriate Solution../

Answer (score 3):

making discoverable forever -

Intent discoverableIntent = new Intent(BluetoothAdapter.ACTION_REQUEST_DISCOVERABLE);
discoverableIntent.putExtra(BluetoothAdapter.EXTRA_DISCOVERABLE_DURATION, 0);
startActivity(discoverableIntent);

a value of 0 means the device is always discoverable.

I know, this was posted 2 months back. But there was no answer anyway, so i just thought of replying. :) 
Hope it helps you.

Comment: @ stashi.. i have tried this but observed it works for ICS devices,Not for lower versions..BTW Thanks for the reply:)